# Error in Python : List index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, recommendation-engine

```
def item(id):
return posts.loc[posts['post_id'] == id]['title'].tolist()[0]

def get_recommendations(postid, num, indices):
idx = indices[postid]
sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_similarities[idx]))
sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
sim_scores = sim_scores[1:num+1]
# print(sim_scores)
indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
print("Recommending " + str(num) + " posts similar to \"" + item(postid) + "\" ...")
return posts.iloc[indices]
```

This is my code and when I run it I get the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-54719cff7892> in <module>()
----> 1 show_recomm('5d6d39567fa40e1417a4931c', 10, indices)

1 frames
<ipython-input-45-dfd12eb7d387> in show_recomm(postid, num, indices)
      6     print(similarity_scores)
      7     indices = [i[0] for i in similarity_scores]
----> 8     print("Recommending " + str(num) + " posts similar to \"" + item(postid) + "\" ...")
      9     return posts.iloc[indices, :-1]

<ipython-input-44-6739fecf9da1> in item(id)
      1 def item(id):
----> 2     return posts.loc[data['post_id'] == id]['title'].tolist()[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I get this error when I try the function with different post ids. For some, I get the output, for other ids I don't.

Comment: You should get this error when none of the post_ids in your data match your requested id. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can see above. It seems it's due to

```py
data['post_id'] == id
```

This would be either true or false. Did you mean

```py
def item(id):
    return posts.loc[id]['title'].tolist()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution helped.